# Pandoc returning Either type

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I'm lost as to where to step next in debugging this issue after some searching of similar but not quite the same errors.

Relevant lines from [this Haskell script](https://github.com/leonstafford/pandoctest/blob/master/Main.hs)

```
import Text.Pandoc (writePlain, readHtml, def, pandocVersion)

convert :: String -> String
convert = writePlain def . readHtml def
```

Are resulting in this error:

```
Main.hs:11:28: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Either
                             Text.Pandoc.Error.PandocError Text.Pandoc.Definition.Pandoc’
                     with ‘Text.Pandoc.Definition.Pandoc’
      Expected type: String -> Text.Pandoc.Definition.Pandoc
        Actual type: String
                     -> Either
                          Text.Pandoc.Error.PandocError Text.Pandoc.Definition.Pandoc
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘readHtml def’
      In the expression: writePlain def . readHtml def
      In an equation for ‘convert’:
          convert = writePlain def . readHtml def
```

Environment details:

- GHC 8.0.1
- Cabal 1.24
- Arch x64 4.10.9

with `pandoc` having been `cabal install`'d

Thanks to answer, comment and a few hours of bashing head against wall, working solution as below:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
import Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as TLE
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Error
import Data.Set

htmlToPlainText :: String -> String
htmlToPlainText = writePlain (def {
    writerExtensions = Data.Set.filter (/= Ext_raw_html) (writerExtensions def)
  }) . handleError . readHtml def

main :: IO ()
main = do
    response <- simpleHttp "https://leonstafford.github.io"

    let body = TLE.decodeUtf8 ( response )
    let bodyAsString = TL.unpack ( body )

    putStrLn $ htmlToPlainText bodyAsString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the types of the two functions you're trying to compose:

[`readHtml`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.19.2.1/docs/Text-Pandoc.html#v:readHtml)`:: ReaderOptions Reader options -> String -> Either PandocError Pandoc`

`readHtml` is an operation that can fail. To represent this, it returns *either* a PandocError or a valid Pandoc.

[`writePlain`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.19.2.1/docs/Text-Pandoc.html#v:writePlain)`:: WriterOptions -> Pandoc -> String`

`writePlain` expects a valid Pandoc only.

The program must handle both cases:

1. `readHtml` returns a Left/error value
2. `readHtml` returns a Right/valid value

This can be done in various ways, but for example:

```
import Text.Pandoc (writePlain, readHtml, def, pandocVersion)

convert :: String -> String
convert = case readHtml def of
  Left err -> show err
  Right doc -> writePlain def doc
```

`Either a b` is similar to `Maybe a` if you're familiar with that, except it can have extra information in the case of a failure. By convention, the `Left` constructor is used to represent an error value, and `Right` constructor is used to represent a normal value.

Comment: Better to change the type signature of `convert` to `String -> Either PandocError String`, so that the caller of this `convert` function can take reasonable steps to react to an error. The type system is trying to warn you that `String -> String` is not a good type for this function. Further evidence: you had to write `show err` in your `Left` case, which is obviously not a good result from this function.